# Using strip() to remove only one element

Tags: python

I have a word within two opening and closing parenthesis, like this `((word))`.
I want to remove the first and the last parenthesis, so they are not duplicate, in order to obtain something like this: `(word)`.

I have tried using `strip('()')` on the variable that contains `((word))`. However, it removes ALL parentheses at the beginning and at the end. Result: `word`.

Is there a way to specify that I only want the first and last one removed?

Comment: .replace('((', '(').replace('))', ')')

Comment: re.sub(r"^\((.+)\)$", r"\1", word)

Comment: `'(' + word.strip('()') + ')'` would remove any number and add back one outer pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you could slice the string and only keep from the second character until the second to last character:

```
word = '((word))'
new_word = word[1:-1]
print(new_word)
```

Produces:

`(word)`

For varying quantities of parenthesis, you could `count` how many exist first and pass this to the slicing as such (this **leaves** only 1 bracket on each side, if you want to remove *only* the first and last bracket you can use the first suggestion);

```
word ='((((word))))'
quan = word.count('(')
new_word = word[quan-1:1-quan]
print(new_word)
```

Produces;

`(word)`

Comment: I have other words as well that differ in their length and number of parentheses surrounding them, but I always want the first and last one removed.

Comment: Edited my answer to take into account different amount of parenthesis (the length of the word doesn't matter here)

Comment: Doesn't this remove more brackets than the first and the last one as asked for by @MeAll? Admittedly, the questions suggests to keep only the inner-most brackets.

Comment: @gofvonx I see what you mean, although if that is the case then my first suggestion should suffice!

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex.

```
import re
word = '((word))'
re.findall('(\(?\w+\)?)', word)[0]
```

This only keeps one pair of brackets.

Answer (score 2):

you can `replace` double opening and double closing parentheses, and set the `max` parameter to 1 for both operations

```
print('((word))'.replace('((','(',1).replace('))',')',1) )
```

But this will not work if there are more occurrences of double closing parentheses
Maybe reversing the string before replacing the closing ones will help

```
t= '((word))'
t = t.replace('((','(',1)
t = t[::-1]  # see string reversion topic [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python]
t = t.replace('))',')',1) )
t = t[::-1]  # and reverse again
```

Answer (score 2):

instead use str.replace, so you would do `str.replace('(','',1)`

basically you would replace all '(' with '', but the third argument will only replace n instances of the specified substring (as argument 1), hence you will only replace the first '('

read the documentation :

replace(...)
    S.replace (old, new[, count]) -> string

```
Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Answer (score 2):

Well , I used regular expression for this purpose and substitute a bunch of brackets with a single one using `re.sub` function

```
import re
s="((((((word)))))))))"
t=re.sub(r"\(+","(",s)
g=re.sub(r"\)+",")",t)
print(g)
```

**Output**

```
(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below:

```
>>> import re
>>> w = '((word))'
>>> re.sub(r'([()])\1+', r'\1', w)
'(word)'
>>> w = 'Hello My ((word)) into this world'
>>> re.sub(r'([()])\1+', r'\1', w)
'Hello My (word) into this world'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
str="((word))"

str[1:len(str)-1]

print (str)
```

And output is = `(word)`